# Restore windows 7 without “system repair disk”

Tags: windows, windows-7, system-restore

I have a blank hard drive. I also have a Windows 7 system image backed up on an external hard drive. I don't have a system repair disk **(SRD)** and also don't have Windows 7 disk. I only have the recovery disks that came with my laptop. There is no option in the recovery disk to restore from a system image. So, I am forced to use the old stuff in the recovery disk.

I have two questions -

1. Can I restore my system from an image on a USB based HDD, without
   any **SRD** ?
2. Can I create an SRD in a windows 8 system for a windows 7 system ? I
   know this might sound strange, but what if an SRD is just a
   collection of backup utilities ?
3. If no microsoft based answer is there, then is there any commercial
   software which can do this instead ?

I don't even have access to an original Windows 7 disk right now. So, that option is ruled out too.

Thanks.

Comment: Admin, now this question is duplicated on this forum. please merge. thanks.